# Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently building an app to read data through an api and I am trying to parse a JSON api from JSON Placeholder.

I made a model class for the Users (.dart):

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final userLogin = userLoginFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

UserLogin userLoginFromJson(String str) => UserLogin.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userLoginToJson(UserLogin data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserLogin {
  UserLogin({
    this.response,
    this.status,
    this.data,
  });

  Response? response;
  Status? status;
  Data? data;

  factory UserLogin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserLogin(
    response: Response.fromJson(json["response"]),
    status: Status.fromJson(json["status"]),
    data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "response": response?.toJson(),
    "status": status?.toJson(),
    "data": data?.toJson(),
  };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.isRegisterComplete,
    this.userId,
  });

  String? isRegisterComplete;
  String? userId;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    isRegisterComplete: json["isRegisterComplete"],
    userId: json["user_id"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "isRegisterComplete": isRegisterComplete,
    "user_id": userId,
  };
}

class Response {
  Response({
    this.datetime,
    this.accessToken,
  });

  DateTime? datetime;
  String? accessToken;

  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Response(
    datetime: DateTime.parse(json["datetime"]),
    accessToken: json["accessToken"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "datetime": datetime?.toIso8601String(),
    "accessToken": accessToken,
  };
}

class Status {
  Status({
    this.code,
    this.description,
    this.message,
  });

  String? code;
  String? description;
  String? message;

  factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Status(
    code: json["code"],
    description: json["description"],
    message: json["message"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "code": code,
    "description": description,
    "message": message,
  };
}
```

This is the JSON information i'm trying to read although its only a small part of it:

```
{
  "response": {
    "datetime": "2021-11-01 19:28:12",
    "accessToken": "BearereyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ"
  },
  "status": {
    "code": "200",
    "description": "Success",
    "message": ""
  },
  "data": {
    "isRegisterComplete": "2",
    "user_id": "00001"
  }
}
```

The error i am currently running into is:

```
E/flutter (30002): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'
```

How do i rectify this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the error message, you are trying to pass a list to a map.

first you need to decode json file :

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(response.body);
```

then pass that map to your fuction somewhere :

```
Status.fromJson(jsonMap);
```